# Regex to Match [] and () and replace it

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text and want to remove everything in between the brackets `[]` and `()`.

> Bengaluru (BengalÅ«ru, [ËˆbeÅ‹É¡É™É­uËÉ¾u] ( listen)) also known as
>   Bangalore, is the third largest city in India and is the center of
>   India's fifth-largest metropolitan area. Located in southern India on
>   the Deccan Plateau, it is the capital of the southern Indian state of
>   Karnataka. Bangalore is known as the "Silicon Valley of India" because
>   of its role as the nation's leading information technology (IT)
>   exporter.[5][6][7] Located at a height of over 3,000 feet (914.4 m)
>   above sea level, Bangalore is known for its pleasant climate
>   throughout the year.It is the highest metro city in India.[8] The city
>   is amongst the top ten preferred entrepreneurial locations in the
>   world.[9]

Regex am trying but doesnt work

```
#\[\(.+?)\]#s
```

and

```
#\(\(.+?)\)#s
```

How can i removed the those content from the above para?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the text contains nested parentheses, you'll need a recursive solution. Fortunately, PCRE supports recursion, so this is easy.

The following regex should do the trick:

```
\[([^\[\]]|(?R))*]|\(([^()]|(?R))*\)
```

It basically contains two parts — one for matching everything inside simple brackets (`(...)`), and one for matching everything inside square-brackets (`[...]`).

Regex autopsy:

```
\[            # match '['
(             # start group 1
 [^\[\]]      #   match any character except '[' and ']'
 |            #   OR
 (?R)         #   recursively match the entire pattern
)*            # repeat zero or more times
]             # match ']'

|             # OR

\(            # match '('
(             # start group 2
 [^()]        #   match any character except '(' and ')'
 |            #   OR
 (?R)         #   recursively match the entire pattern
)*            # repeat zero or more times
\)            # match ')'
```

[**Regex101 demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pM6eT6/2)

Comment: That'll choke on the nested parentheses.

Comment: +1. It's a pity there's no nice way to combine the recursive patterns :-)

Comment: +1 This is really great use of recursive sub pattern.